# Shortened links to topics and examples in Documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation, hyperlinks, documentation-topics, documentation-examples

So here's the link given to topics in Documentation:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/tag-name/topic-id/topic-name
```

And here for examples:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/tag-name/topic-id/topic-name/example-id/example-name
```

Now that is a *huge* link, especially for examples such as [Using Lambda Expressions to Sort a Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/91/lambda-expressions/387/using-lambda-expressions-to-sort-a-collection) with long names and decently long topic names.

Let's shorten them. Like posts in Q&A, I'd favor URLs like

```
https://stackoverflow.com/t/topic-id
```

For topics, and

```
https://stackoverflow.com/e/example-id
```

For examples.

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why does the link size matter? It seems to me the SEO benefits outweigh the fact that is may be visually less pleasing.

Comment: What SEO benefits are there in those massive links?

Comment: Relevancy is affected by certain keywords in the content, title, and URL. Granted, every search engine is different and is constantly changing, there is at least some weight to the URL: https://moz.com/learn/seo/url

Comment: @JeremyHarris But there's also the /q/question-id and /a/answer-id links. I'm not proposing that the actual links be changed, I'm proposing _new_ links to _redirect_ to the actual links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are slightly longer versions than the ones you propose in place already:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/t/<topic-id>
http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/e/<example-id>
```

Comment: What does the `/s/` bit mean?

Comment: @StephenLeppik "Short", probably. Or "share"? I don't know how those came to be, exactly.

Comment: I guess it doesn't really matter—they're there so that it can distinguish between those links, and topics in the [t] and [e] tags.